# html_entity_decode nesting php

Tags: php, html

running php 5.6.29 here.

Processing about 6,000 rows of data from a MYSQL Table. Looking at the HTML Description column and making changes.  Using html_entity_decode to show the changed result in the Browser.

The problem is, each row is displaying the HTML result **nested** inside the previous row, which makes the display impossible.  Obviously I want each row to have a clean break. As these are tables, it seems not to break?

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $i++;

    echo "<br>$i";
    echo "<br>Product: ".$row['id'];
    echo "<br>Title: ".$row['title'];
    echo "<br>";

    $a = $row['html'];
    echo "htmlspecialchars_decode($a)";
```

//...change the html process here ...

```
    $b = html_entity_decode($row['html']);
    echo "<br><br><br>".$b;

    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";


    }
```

I checked this in multiple browsers, so it's not just Chrome.  Basically I somehow need to close the HTML before I move onto the next row right? Or is this some kind of limitation or bug? tia.

Comment: What do you mean by "nested"? `echo "htmlspecialchars_decode($a)";` doesn't call `htmlspecialchars_decode` function by the way. If you want to call the function, remove double quotes. If you have issues with the markup, then you should include it into the question, at least.

Comment: What is `$row['html']`? `<br>`s shouldnt "nest", it's just a new line.

Comment: I mean the 2nd row is appearing inside the 1st row. The 3rd row is nested inside the 2nd row. "Product" and "Title" do not appear again at all.

Comment: Show the generated source.

Comment: That won't answer my question Chris.